# PostgreSQL query which should include null values also in master table

Tags: string, postgresql, join, select

I my beginner to PostgresQL,Can u please help me in the below issue

I have master and detail table like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9x1M.png)

if image is not clear,I am giving sample like this

```
master table                           detail table
-----------                           --------------

dept_no   dept_name             dept_no emp_no  emp_name  emp_desig

1         Marketing               1      E001   saritha   Sales Manager
2         R&D                     1      E002   latha     Sales Executive
3         HR                      2      E003   veena     Coder
4         IT                      3      E004   geetha    Manager
5         Testing                 3      E005   Kavin     Field Officer
```

I need the result something like this below,which should include dept_name having null values also,

```
dept_name      emp_name

Marketing      saritha,latha
R&D            veena
HR             geetha,kavin
IT 
Testing
```

Can anybody help me in this query,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to `LEFT JOIN` your tables?

Comment: "help me" is not a valid SO question. Don't ask us to do your homework. [ask] Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. All the parts to this are clearly basic beginner faqs.. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table.

Comment: @Daria, I need to,I think I need a deep study in postgresql

Comment: @philipxy,I will improve my question in future,sorry i did asked in wrong way

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
select dept_name, string_agg(emp_name,',')
from master
left join detail
on master.dept_no = detail.dept_no
group by master.dept_no, dept_name
order by master.dept_no;
 dept_name |  string_agg   
-----------+---------------
 Marketing | latha,saritha
 R&D       | veena
 HR        | kavin,geetha
 IT        | 
 Testing   | 
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you very much pifor for your immediate response.It works for me.